# What is the result of the integral of the product of two Weibull functions?

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve the "pdf" integral shown in the formula below.
The required integral to be solved is the product of two 3-parameter Weibull functions multiplied by $\frac{1}{z}$.

I tried solving it by integrating by parts for three functions but with no result.
I also tried to solve as an integral of a binomial and exponential function but always the ($\frac{1}{z}$) makes it harder to be solved.

I tried to use Leibniz's general rule. However, Leibniz rule states that any product of two derivatives (ex: du.dv) are negligible because they have small values compared with the original values of u and v.

I tried to assume it as a product of two exponentials with variance = 1 giving Chi-squared. However, I am seeking for a more general formula which makes it not reliable to assume such simplification.

$$pdf = \int_0^\infty \frac{\alpha_y \alpha_z}{\beta_y \beta_z}\frac{1}{z}\biggr(\frac{\frac{t}{z}-\mu_y}{\beta_y}\biggr)^{\alpha_y-1}\biggr(\frac{z-\mu_z}{\beta_z}\biggr)^{\alpha_z-1}\exp\biggr(-\biggr(\frac{\frac{t}{z}-\mu_y}{\beta_y}\biggr)^{\alpha_y}\biggr)\exp\biggr(-\biggr(\frac{z-\mu_z}{\beta_z}\biggr)^{\alpha_z}\biggr)dz$$